# I was expecting a function to return bool, but "this expression was expected to have type 'int * int * string' but here has type 'string' "

Tags: f#, tuples

I am working this problem on my own, and after four hours I am closer to finishing part 3.1.1 but cannot explain why I can't get it to return a boolean value, especially since a similar function is happy to do string concatenation.

```
(*
3.1 A time of day can be represented as a 
triple (hours, minutes, f) 
where f is either AM or PM – or as a record. 

Declare a function to test whether one time of day comes 
before another. 

For example, (11,59,"AM") comes before (1,15,"PM"). 

Make solutions with triples as well as with records. 

Declare the functions in infix notation.

Hansen, Michael R.; Rischel, Hans. 
Functional Programming Using F# (p. 66). 
Cambridge University Press. Kindle Edition. 
*)

type TimeOfDayTriple = int * int * string

let (<.) ((hour1, min1, pod1):TimeOfDayTriple) ((hour2, min2, pod2):TimeOfDayTriple) =
    true
//val ( <. ) : int * int * string -> int * int * string -> bool

let (<.) ((hour1, min1, pod1):TimeOfDayTriple) ((hour2, min2, pod2):TimeOfDayTriple) =
    (pod1, pod2)
//val ( <. ) : int * int * string -> int * int * string -> string * string

let (<.) ((hour1, min1, pod1):TimeOfDayTriple) ((hour2, min2, pod2):TimeOfDayTriple) =
    pod1 + pod2
val ( <. ) : int * int * string -> int * int * string -> string
    
let (<.) ((hour1, min1, pod1):TimeOfDayTriple) ((hour2, min2, pod2):TimeOfDayTriple) =
    pod1 < pod2;;
//Ch03.fsx(32,5): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
//    'int * int * string'    
//but here has type
//    'string'
```

Comment: Did you by any chance redefine operator `(<)` somewhere above?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you may get this error if you accidentally redefine the `<` operator. I personally prefer to avoid custom operators unless there is some special reason for them (e.g. parser combinators, which is an established domain for them).

I think you avoid a lot of troubles if you just define a custom function `compareTimes` (possibly after restarting your REPL).

It is worth noting that you can also use operator overloading in F#. That's not something the book exercise is asking, but it may be good to know. To define a type that supports the standard `<`, `>` etc. operators, you could use:

```
[<CustomComparison>]
type TimeOfDayTriple = 
  | TOD of int * int * string
  interface System.IComparable<TimeOfDayTriple> with
    member x.CompareTo(TOD(h2, m2, p2)) =
      let (TOD(h1, m1, p1)) = x
      // (implement comparison here)
```

Comment: I did.  Then I tried to undo it, but there's a good chance I didn't succeed in clearing the environment.  In fsx scripting mode is there a way to clear the REPL environment without closing VisualStudio?

Comment: I think you right-click and an option to restart or reset appears